# How long Android's application main thread can be busy without loosing performance

Tags: android, performance, frame-rate, ui-thread

Android app must do something in UI thread a.k.a. main thread (at least update UI).

How long Android's application can do something in UI thread without loosing performance (no UI jittering etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for 60fps your magic boundary is 16ms. If you don't need more than 16ms you won't skip frames, thus, introducing no UI lag, etc.

Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaMTIgxCSqU (around minute 2 the implications for developers are layed out)

Comment: 1. is is explained more precisely somewhere? 2. where the 60fps is defined? 3. how much less than those 16ms?

Comment: I just added one of the android performance pattern youtube videos. This might be a good point to dive deeper ("PerfMatters" - Video go deeper into this topic)

Comment: you asked wrong question, as it implicates that you wana do something which may take longer ... so the question is why you bother about this (what you wana do on main thread?) and why you could not move it out of this thread

Comment: actually I was asked this question on a job interview and I was surprised as I had no idea about those 60fps

Comment: Re, 2. the exact refresh rate can be found at runtime http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate()